# How can I sense Infrared Light properly to detect direction of Motion

Tags: infrared, photodiode, attiny, motion

I've designed the schematic below:

[image]

Basically, I want to detect direction of motion at a door frame from the top to turn on or off a relay which is probably connected to lights. The phototransistors will be 6 centimeters away from each other and there will be two IR LEDs in the middle.

I have four concerns in mind:

1. The current at IR_A and IR_B has a great range from 1 mA to 100 nA and the voltage on these diodes become nearly equal to VCC when low light is present. I compare the voltage signal on the photodiodes with "Sensitivity pot" voltage, but I would have hard time when photodiode voltage is close to VCC because only a fraction of a degree turn would make a difference. How can I make a better comparator setup? I thought of implementing a logarithmic reading in the code so that the pot readings would be interpreted exponentially instead of linear. Is there a better yet simple solution? Maybe I can switch to different resistors with MOSFETs depending on the range (similar to an auto-range multimeter).
2. I pulse the IR transmitter LEDs with high current for maximum brightness and sensitivity. The code is like:

[image: code]

I learned single conversion lasts around 100us for 10 bit measurement thus 0.325 amps will pass for around 200-250us from the LEDs and then there will be a 32ms sleep time. Even though the duty cycle is really low will I damage the LEDs? Can I go for even higher currents? Datasheet says current surge can be 1A and pulse can be 200mA for 100us, doesn't say anything about higher durations. Also, to not disturb the microcontroller, I've arranged a totem pole which costs a few cents only.

3. To not disturb the power rail as I turn on the LEDs, I've added two decoupling capacitors (C6 and C5) but how can I make sure I've selected the right capacitance? It must be about the formulas that are used to choose the output capacitor when designing a power supply (ripple voltage).
4. I've burned a few relays back then when I was switching power supplies. This time, I will connect the relay to 220V LED bulbs directly. I hope there will be no inrush current of the internal power supplies. The relay is relatively small, so I wanted to make sure.
   [relay datasheet](https://www.citrelay.com/Catalog%20Pages/RelayCatalog/J102.pdf)

Note: I am open to any suggestions, I don't know if I can pull this project off because there is light, reflections that have different angles depending on the person's height, scatter, distance, complexity of human motion. I hope I've chosen the correct way to determine direction of motion.

[SFH213 photodiode datasheet](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-5488352/SFH%20213%20FA_EN.pdf)

[TSHF6410 IR LED datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81832/tshf6410.pdf)

[BSH103 MOSFET datasheet](https://octopart.com/datasheet/bsh103%2C215-nexperia-78739323)

In physical placement , Blue dots are phototransistors, Red dots are IR LEDs:

After both sensors are triggered, MCU will look which sensor looses the signal first and decide which way the person is going, will count the people inside, if counter > 0 lights lit, else lights off.

[image: physical setup]

Comment: Could you add a little sketch of the physical layout of the sensors and LEDs?  And what it is that you want to detect?

Comment: Done, all four components will be through drilled holes of a plastic box.

Comment: Make sure you have proper creaepage and clearance with the AC

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to get calibration like this to work reliably.

Here are some alternatives to consider.  I think the laser-pair and the ultrasonic rangefinder are the easiest to do.

### Lasers

If you have two lasers and two detectors on opposite sides of the door, you will have two beams which are cut very reliably.  It's the trivial to determine ingress/egress direction.

To make wiring simpler, this is often done with a laser and its sensor in the same housing, aimed at a reflector.  Using a [retroreflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector) makes alignment easy, and can be just a piece of tape or something like a bicycle reflector.  You don't have to use lasers, but they are often small and easier to use than a collimated beam.

[image]

### Ultrasonic

Ultrasonic sensors are available as rangefinders; a typical model is [MB1010 LV-MaxSonar-EZ1](https://maxbotix.com/products/mb1010), available packaged in many forms from eg Digilent.  This is pretty much designed for people detection, so should get good results except for two people squeezing past each other through the door.  You get typically a distance measurement at ~10 Hz; a simple matter to see whether it's rising or falling.  Mouted at an angle should give the result you need.  (1.8 metre door, 45 degrees: floor is 2.5 m and stable.  A person would be about 1 m away and rising or falling.)

Another possibility is to use [doppler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect), where the change in pitch indicates the direction.  This is a good technique but will give trouble where the speed of the person is very slow.

### PIR sensors

You might find PIR sensors, one each side of the door, will give you very good motion detection.

Comment: I agree, I was having hard time choosing emitter angle, receiver distance. I've considered lasers before but I have to put two separate boxes well I guess I will continue with lasers anyway because reliability is priority. PIR doesn't give continuous information so I think it will have hard time to see the exact motion. I didn't understan how ultrasonic sensor would give direction? Will I have two separate ultrasonic distance sensors and compare the measurements?

Comment: I updated my answer with a little more info, hope it's helpful.

Comment: Ooh the reflector, how couldn't I think of it. Also now I understood how you positioned the ultrasonic sensor it also makes sense, thank you. The ultrasonic isn't very suitable for doors at tight corridors however.

Answer (score 0):

An idea that simplifies comparison of photodiodes...

In this scheme, the two separated photodiodes operate near photovoltaic mode, which will be slower than OP's scheme, but will operate a bit more toward logarithmic fashion, which OP likes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRGkwd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Photodiode currents are opposed-summed, so if they are equally illuminated, ADC will be half-**ADC_ref**. These photodiodes have about 11pf capacitance each. Assume 10pf stray capacitance and another 10pf ADC input capacitance. After turning on LEDs, wait for a few timeconstants before triggering ADC measurement - at least 100us. You can speed response time by reducing R3 & R4 at the expense of sensitivity, away from log-response (toward linear response).

An ADC measurement less than 512 (of 1023 max) indicates that one photodiode got more light than the other - greater than 512 indicates the opposite.

**However** you need to take *another* ADC measurement with LEDs off so that you can accommodate ambient light. This measurement should be substituted for the 512 reading as described above.

- zero **sum**
- lights off, **sum** += ADC.......................ambient light measurement
- lights on, **sum** -= ADC........................measurement due to LED
- **sum** > upper threshold? -> someone entered
- **sum** < lower threshold? -> someone left

The progress of ADC measurements as time passes might produce the following sequence of ADC **sum** samples. The slope of the mid-point crossing would indicate whether a target is entering or exiting (at least for a well-behaved target).
[image: sequence of ADC sum samples] 
 You can take very many measurements each second, so consider doing multiple light-on/lights-off measurements and adding/subtracting results before deciding to compare against thresholds. You may have to calculate dynamic threshold levels based on ambient measurements. I have used this method to extend the range of a photo-reflector LED/photodiode combo from 1cm to nearly 2m.

Any reflective arrangement has significant problems with specular reflections from glasses, hats, strange clothing patterns, bald heads, hair versus cloth, etc. These will be *very* difficult to overcome. I'm thinking that you'd get multiple enter/leave indications from one person's motion through the doorway.
Another problem involves detecting short people, where reflective signals are smaller, and where LED angle of 10 degrees makes reflected signals give similar reflected light to both photodiodes.